# Permission issue on restore of the db from primary to secondary

Tags: sql-server, errors, sqlcmd

while restoring the User DB from primary to secondary replica through query in cmd prompt and got following error message

> Msg 262, Level 14, State 1, CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.
>
> RESTORE LOG is terminating abnormally.Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, RESTORE LOG is terminating abnormally.

provided sa permission on the user, but still it did not work. where should i need to look.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64868/create-database-permission-denied-for-sysadmin

Comment: What was the command that causes this error? It's strange that you've got the restore LOG error, but when you restored full backup, it's just restored without any error?

Answer (score 0):

Permissions

from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql

> If the database being restored does not exist, the user must have
>   CREATE DATABASE permissions to be able to execute RESTORE. If the
>   database exists, RESTORE permissions default to members of the
>   sysadmin and dbcreator fixed server roles and the owner (dbo) of the
>   database (for the FROM DATABASE_SNAPSHOT option, the database always
>   exists). RESTORE permissions are given to roles in which membership
>   information is always readily available to the server. Because fixed
>   database role membership can be checked only when the database is
>   accessible and undamaged, which is not always the case when RESTORE is
>   executed, members of the db_owner fixed database role do not have
>   RESTORE permissions.

Comment: I have sysadmin privileges,tried to restore the DB from primary server to secondary replica through SQLCMD and i got this error when i execute  directly it is executing sqlcmd -E -S SQL1 -d master -Q "RESTORE DATABASE [tes] FROM  DISK = N'\\sql2\share\test.bak' WITH  NORECOVERY, STATS = 5"
sqlcmd -E -S SQL1 -d master -Q "RESTORE LOG [tes] FROM  DISK = N'\\sql2\share\tu.trn' WITH  NORECOVERY,  STATS = 5"

Comment: when i tried to execute this script  by declaring scalar variable with the below query i got the error.

Comment: as you can see from the script i am using backup file which is network drive to restore this in secondary.

Comment: I added SQL Server and agent service account to shared drive, my id has been added in local administrator in secondary as well.

Comment: I wanted to schedule this script through Job

Comment: Have you checked that the SQL account have permissions to create mdf and ldf files on the local storage as well?

Comment: I ensured to add sql service account in both data drive and log drive in secondary server but still no luck this is the query i am using set restorestring= sqlcmd -S  secondaryservername E Q  RESTORE log  nextdb 
 FROM  DISK primaryservername share @nextdb trn
WITH  NORECOVERY,  NOUNLOAD  STATS = 5
exec xpcmdshell restorestring  as you know i am trying to run this from sqlcmd  from primary i removed double slash and plus sign from the query

Comment: i also declared restore string in the begining of the query when i run the query using sqlcmd in the primary 
sqlcmd -E -S QAMRPSQL1 -d master -Q "RESTORE DATABASE [tes] FROM  DISK = N'\\qamrpsql2\share\[tes].bak' WITH  NORECOVERY, STATS = 5"  this is working fine

Comment: I fixed this error by adding sa and it s password in the restore script and it worked.

Comment: @Vijaya you haven't fixed it, just weakened the security of the entire server I am afraid. You should really sort out permissions of the account that is invoking the restore.